# HTTP request works in curl but not iOS or Postman

Tags: ios, http, curl

***I'm very new to HTTP networking.

Basically, this works:
curl -k -L -v -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header 'Authorization: OAuth someAccessToken' --header "Force-Instance-Url: websiteurl" --header "Force-User-Id: someUserId" --data "{}" "websiteurl"

However, I can't seem to have any success getting a response in either Postman (the HTTP test plugin for chrome) or in a program I made in iOS. The results are always HTTP Status 500 - java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input.

I've been very careful to make sure the urls and headers are exactly the same but no luck.
In my iOS program, I have an http request that successfuly retrieves an access token, instance_url, and force_user_id. I use these fields to make the request as posted above but the response is error 500.

Since it doesn't work in postman either I'm not sure if it helps to post my code but I will anyways:

```
NSURL *loginURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"websiteurl"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:loginURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *instance_url = [self.loginDictionary objectForKey:@"instance_url"];
NSString *authorization = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"OAuth ",[self.loginDictionary objectForKey:@"access_token"]];
NSString *instance_id = [self.loginDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
NSRange range = [instance_id rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    instance_id = [instance_id substringFromIndex:range.location + 1];
}
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
[request setValue:authorization forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"];
[request setValue:instance_url forHTTPHeaderField: @"Force-Instance-Url"];
[request setValue:instance_id forHTTPHeaderField: @"Force-User-Id"];
NSLog(@"\n\n%@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
     {
         self.loginDictionary = (NSDictionary *) JSON;
         NSLog(@"*************************************************************************");
         NSLog(@"*************************************************************************");
         NSLog(@"FIREWORKS");
     }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
     {
         NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]); 
     }];
[operation start];
```

Here is a log print out of the request headers.

```
{
Accept = "application/json";
Authorization = "OAuth accessTokenValue";
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
"Force-Instance-Url" = "websiteurl";
"Force-User-Id" = someUserId;
}
```

On a final note, the only thing that seems like a clue to me is the fact that the auth header in the curl command is in single quotes but the rest are not... I'm not sure if this is important or not.
Thanks for reading and helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

curl automatically adds some headers. In your example it will send `Host: websiteurl`and `Content-Length: 2`

Comment: Hmm I tried adding both of those headers but I still receive the same error. Thanks though.

Comment: Where do you send the empty Object ({}) in your code? The error says: `No content to map to Object due to end of input.`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. What empty object?

Comment: Someone else helped me get postman working by entering {} in the form data field! This seems to be similar to what you are saying. Any idea how to do this in iOS?

Comment: The problem is solved by adding:
`NSString *empty = @"{}";
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[empty UTF8String] length:[empty length]];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];`
Thanks @jdb !